# React Stoplight Component: Colors Not Changing After Timeout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to solve a react problem.
I followed the below youtube tutorial.
I am trying in code sandbox.
for some reason the colors of the signal no appearing and its not changing after sometime.
I even gave set timeout.
Can you let me know how to fix it. Providing my code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/traffic-tkfjl5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A19%2C15

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plFo3jJRTdE&list=PL6x5Q-Sj_Bla3_wMqhETxMBjFml0XJNPI&index=13

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
type stopLightState = "stop" | "slow" | "go";
const stop_delay = 3000;
const slow_delay = 2000;

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<stopLightState>("stop");
  function getStopLightClass(light: StopLightState) {
    return `light $(light)` + (state === light ? "on" : "");
    // stop interpolate
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state === "stop") {
      setTimeout(() => setState("go"), stop_delay);
    } else if (state === "slow") {
      setTimeout(() => setState("slow"), slow_delay);
    }
  }, [state]);
  return (
    <div className="stopLight">
      {/* <div className={"light stop" + (state === "stop" ? " on" : "")}>here</div> */}
      <div className={getStopLightClass("stop")}>here</div>

      <div className={getStopLightClass("slow")}>here</div>
      <div className={getStopLightClass("go")}>here</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `\`light $(light)\`` that's not how you insert a value into a template literal.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.  Squiggly brackets!

Comment: `\`light $(light)\``   `=>`   `\`light ${light}\``

Comment: @James : I updated the changes  in the sandbox but still its not working, providing my updated code sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/traffic-tkfjl5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A11%2C19-11%2C22

Comment: There is no space between the second and third class name. Add an extra space after `${light}`

Comment: @James   thanks for your response I gave extra space but still I don't see red, green, grey and yellow in circles. Similar to traffic light

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/traffic-tkfjl5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A11%2C28

Comment: Your css is not correct.  Get rid of the colon after for example `.go` in  `.go: {background: green;}` - and the rest of the colons in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the corrected version in below link:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/traffic-forked-yz8qj6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A3%2C1

issues:
1- you didn't handle all the states possible (go, slow, stop) inside useEffect

best practices:
1- take out "light" class because it is a shared class between all divs
2- take a look at use of arrow functions
3- you also can use Enums instead of type here